# How to notify object property changed with helper?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My view PasswordBox control have glitch, placeholder keep visible cause property not changed. Placeholder trigger when password property empty string. instead I pass property directly from viewmodel to bind. i pass property from other object. the schema of model is used by viewmodel and DbContext. inside model class i set default value to empty string. if i remove default value for password. the notify work. so, i dont know wheres the problem, notify cant change explicit default with Helper.

View

```
<Grid >
    <PasswordBox helper:PasswordBoxHelper.Password="{Binding User.Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" />
    <TextBlock Padding="12" IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding User.Password}" Value="">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Helper

```
public static class PasswordBoxHelper
{
    public readonly static DependencyProperty PasswordProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Password", typeof(string), typeof(PasswordBoxHelper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnPasswordPropertyChanged));

    public static string GetPassword(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (string)dp.GetValue(PasswordProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPassword(DependencyObject dp, string value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(PasswordProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnPasswordPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pwdBox = sender as PasswordBox;
        pwdBox.PasswordChanged += PasswordChangedHandler;
    }

    private static void PasswordChangedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pwdBox = sender as PasswordBox;
        SetPassword(pwdBox, pwdBox.Password);
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class User
{
    private string _password;
    public User()
    {
      _password = string.Empty;
    }

    public string Password 
    { 
        get => _password; 
        set
        {
            _password = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }    
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public User User { get; } = new();
}
```

Comment: There is no good reason for your dependency property. Just get rid of that. Instead, your User class needs to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. (It's not enough that the class declares some PropertyChanged event; it _needs_ to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Interface implement just optional. with or without. still works.  i have weird, if i'm not set default Password property value. placeholder not exist. but the notify property works as i type. i check it with messagebox. but default value is set. placeholder visible. notify not work whatever i type. it makes placeholder keep visibile. i check it with messagebox. just empty value. weird right?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I checked it with TextBox. it works as expected.  even, i;m not implement property changed in that property. so theres something wrong with my helper. i guess.

Comment: Besides that it is still unclear why you are doing this, you are also still attaching a PasswordChanged handler to the PasswordBox each time the attached Password property changes. This is a severe programming error. Just should also never use the `as` operator without checking the result for null.

Comment: @Clemens I call parent event to pass parent(PasswordBox) property Password to helper property. or my understanding of attached property still wrong.

Comment: "_Interface implement just optional. with or without. still works._" It's not optional, and bindings won't work without it (or at lease only in the direction from the binding target to the source, but not the other way round). But if you insist that it works while at the same time here wondering why it doesn't work, well, i am just getting out of your hair... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace after hour understand and edit and edit the helper class. the magic come, i just pass callback in frameworkmetadata. i remove the default value. it works. but i still dont know in theory, why this works.

Comment: Simply use a TextBox if you don't care about secure user passwords.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using the PasswordBox is to work securely with the SecureString obtained from the SecurePassword property.
If, on the other hand, you don't need secure password management and just need a text box with a feature to hide visible characters, it's much easier to use a TextBox with a masking font.

My example from [another topic (in Russian)](https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2900809.html):

```xml
    <Window.Resources>
        <vms:LauncherViewModel x:Key="viewModel" Pin="123456789"/>
        <FontFamily x:Key="passowrdFont">pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#password</FontFamily>
    </Window.Resources>
```

```xml
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="pinBox" Text="{Binding Pin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=passwordHide}"
                                        Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource passowrdFont}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
        <ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        x:Name="passwordHide"
                        IsChecked="True">
            <FrameworkElement.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Показать"/>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{materialDesign:PackIcon Eye}"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Скрыть"/>
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{materialDesign:PackIcon EyeOff}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </FrameworkElement.Resources>
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
```

[Font file.](https://www.cyberforum.ru/attachments/1294544d1636747673)

And for Placeholder Text, it's better to change the template or style of the TextBox.
An example from [my other thread](https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2991541.html#post16269201).

```xml
        <Style x:Key="TextBox.Placeholder.Style" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.IsEmpty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <VisualBrush>
                                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Fill me up!"/>
                                </VisualBrush.Visual>
                            </VisualBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
 
 
        <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource TextBox.Placeholder.Style}"/>
```

As for the implementation of the Attached Property for binding PsswordBox.Password, for it to work correctly, you need to pass the value in both directions and ensure that the listener is connected to the PasswordChanged event once.

Implementation example:

```cs
    public static class PasswordBoxHelper
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty
            = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "Password",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(PasswordBoxHelper),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, PasswordChangedCallback, CoercePasswordCallback));

        private static object CoercePasswordCallback(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
        {
            return baseValue ?? string.Empty;
        }

        public static string GetPassword(PasswordBox pBox)
        {
            return (string)pBox.GetValue(PasswordProperty);
        }

        public static void SetPassword(PasswordBox pBox, string value)
        {
            pBox.SetValue(PasswordProperty, value);
        }

        private static void PasswordChangedCallback(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is not PasswordBox pBox)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("Only for PasswordBox");
            }
            pBox.PasswordChanged -= passwordChanged;
            pBox.Password = (string)e.NewValue;
            pBox.PasswordChanged += passwordChanged;
        }

        private static readonly RoutedEventHandler passwordChanged = (s, _) =>
        {
            PasswordBox pBox = (PasswordBox)s;
            SetPassword(pBox, pBox.Password);
        };
    }
```

Comment: thx for the reply, i already find out the problem. as i guess the problem is come from helper class. inside frameworkmetadata i only use 1 argument the callback. default value inside framework cause this problem. i still dont understand. but it fix it.

Comment: @Blader, Did you read the end of my question in which I wrote about the implementation of the Attached Property?

Comment: Worth to mention wrt SecureString: https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md The official documentation for SecureString (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-6.0#remarks) also explicitly discourages the usage of SecureString.

Comment: Generally speaking, SecureString only offers a false sense of security. An attacker only needs to look out for usages of SecureString and then observe how data (e.g., passwords) are packed into and unpacked from SecureString instances. For an attacker, the SecureString type is like a big flashing neon sign to follow.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, SecureString didn't live up to expectations. Using it is quite difficult. And it doesn't provide the security you expect.
An example of safe work with it: https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2656829.html
I agree with you that this is now out of date.
But along with it, PasswordBox has also become obsolete.
That's why I advise to use TextBox styling instead.

Comment: @EldHasp i dont have problem with software that spy into memory. cause i can just set empty the password property when authentication success.

Comment: @EldHasp, i totally agree...

Comment: @Blader, So then you don't need a PasswordBox. Use a TextBox with a masking font.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Microsoft indeed states that the SecureString is not safe, althought it is safer than plaintext passwords in memory. It recommends the use of advanced authentication flows like Windows authentication or OAuth services. Pushing passwords as plaintext into the memory should always be avoided. It is far less insecure than SecureString. The point with SecureString is that it requires to unwrap the password as string at one point in the authentication flow.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace *"For an attacker, the SecureString type is like a big flashing neon sign to follow."* - That's not true and beside the point.

Comment: @Blader *" i dont have problem with software that spy into memory. cause i can just set empty the password property when authentication success."* - That's dangerously naive. Instances of string passed around the application will be copied (copy by reference). This results in multiple pointers that point to the string. You can't control when the garbage collector collects those references. You simply can't. The can live for the entirety of the application's lifetime. You should learn about authentication before you touch this very sensitive topic. That's why we have so many security leaks.

Comment: @Blader And don't forget the memory management on OS level (paging). Potentially, there will be many copies of the user password in the memory. In managed languages like C#, you have absolutely no control over the memory. Aside from pinning,  there is not much you can do. The official recommendation is to not implement a custom authentication flow. Instead use an existing and advanced one. Deploying your application per user already involves Windows authentication, because Windows forces users to create an account and to login. It can't get much safer in a desktop environment.